# robot framework log suppression

Tags: logging, robotframework

I apologize if this seems unclear, but how do I use the command outlined in this part of the manual.

> The command line option --log (-l) determines where log files are created. >Unless the special value NONE is used, log files are always created and their >default name is log.html.

I am trying to run tests without saving the log each time, and this seems to be the answer, but I don't understand how to use it. Any advice is helpful, thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to have log, then just launch the tests this way:

```
pybot --log NONE path/to/tests
```